# Android Gridview, images don't fit

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with fitting my images in a gridview in Android Studio. Basically I need to have 2 images per row and can scroll down with TextViews on the images but when I scroll back up or down the images change positions to stick together. They have different dimensions in their original format.
Here's my image layout item_district.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/hoverText"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/hoverId"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

GridView layout activity_district.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_district"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="iut.paci.noelcommunity.DistrictActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editAddress"
            android:hint="Your address ..."
            />

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:columnWidth="150dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change your scaleType in xml:  android:scaleType="fitXy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing this problem because your grid item's height is dependent on its content, i.e imageview and ur image rendering is not in sync with your recycled grid item view.
One simple fix would be to fix the grid items height. Apply a height to your grid item's relative layout. 
Its recommended to have same sized items in gridview for best UI.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly :)